# Can't add more menu in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am stuck with wordpress menu. Can't add more menu in one of my site. Don't know why. I think it's riced it's limit. Do u have any solution. I would like to add more than 500 menu / submenu item in my menu.

Thank you

Comment: Without showing any code it's nearly impossible to help, that being said I would guess adding **posts_per_page** to your query with a stupidly high number should do it

Comment: A value of -1 for posts_per_page will yield unlimited results.

Answer (score 2):

**Long Answer**

Each menu item contains several elements (11-12), all of which are posted when the menu form is submitted, everything from the menu id, the order, the menu title, the associated item, the nonce, etc.  So, when you submit a menu with 100 items, you're actually submitting about 1100 separate values.  Generally, that size is limited by the max_input_vars setting in php.ini.  So, when you attempt to submit the menu form that contains more POSTed values that is allowed, the extras are not submitted, and thus the extra items you added to your menu are lost.  This is an intentional setting so that people cannot bring your server to its knees by submitting a  massive post with millions and millions of pieces of data that is then processed.

**tl;dr**

Increase the max_input_vars value in your php.ini to something like 10,000, I bet it's right around 5,000 now.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress Menu (Appearance -> Menus) feature, itself, does not limit the number of menus or menu items you can have.

It's possible that the Theme you're using limits the number of items in a single Menu, but that's not likely (common practice) unless you have multiple levels of sub menus beyond 2 or 3.

A Menu of **Pages** that exceeds a couple dozen is unusual and an indication you're using Pages and the respective Menu feature improperly. In other words: why do you have 500 Pages? In such cases it's usually best to use the wp_list_pages() PHP Function in your Theme (assuming you're a programmer) because you have more control over placement and filtering of it's output.

However, I agree with the comment on your thread that your details are vaugue. If this answer isn't helpful then you should explain what "menu" feature you're referring to, where you're seeing this limit, and why you have so many Pages.